# Laravel send data to view and other function

Tags: laravel

i need to send the same variable to view and function (same controller), i have found this, but it doesn t work good, any ideas?

**Function return**

```
    $this->payments($trans);


    return view('payments')->with(['clients' => $trans]);
```

**payments()**

```
public function payments($trans){

    dd($trans);


    Excel::create('export_list_general', function ($file){

    $file->sheet('export', function ($sheet) use ($trans) {

            $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Client');
            $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'name');
            $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'surname');

            $i = 2;
            foreach ($trans as $tran) {
                $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $i, $tran->name);
                $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $i, $tran->pname);
                $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $i, $tran->psurn);


                $i++;
            }

        });


    })->export('xlsx');

}
```

Comment: code looks fine. show your code and explain where is the error occuring.

Comment: When i do $this->payments($trans); it redirect to the other function, and not to the view 'payments'

Comment: We need to see how your `payments()` method looks like

Comment: Remove `dd($trans)`? I'm not sure what the problem is. First you execute `payments($trans)` and if this code works it will return your view `payments`. There is no return statement in payments. Any errors?

Comment: Are you using `maatwebsite/excel`? what you mean by ` it redirect to the other function, and not to the view 'payments'? which function?`

Comment: i've found the error was a conflict in route

Answer (score 0):

Send data to your function using this

```
YourSameControllerClass::payments($trans);
```

and put view redirection line in payments function

```
public function payments($trans){
    // your code

   return view('payments')->with(['clients' => $trans]);
}
```

Comment: that's not what I asked ... and I know how to send data to a view, whit $this->payments($trans) i wanna send to other function

Comment: you have error in your return view line near `[clients'` your inverted comma is missing

Comment: i just forgot to fix my code, i had tried to do some stuff, but it didn t work

Comment: can you put your `return view('payments')->with(['clients' => $trans]);` in payments() method ? I am not sure but it may help

Answer (score 0):

in payments(), do **return** Excel::create()...

and perhaps assign it to a variable:  $excel = $this->payments($trans);